# DisplayAttribute.Order does not change the order of fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I used scaffolding to generate a view for the model below, in Visual Studio 2013 (.NET 4.5). I added the `Display` annotations afterwards. Why doesn't the `LastName` field appears above the `FirstName` field?

```
public class Order
{
    [Display(Order=15001)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Order=15000)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Does the `DisplayAttribute.Order` documentation say it only works on columns?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute?view=net-5.0

I'm reading Professional ASP.NET MVC 5 by Jon Galloway et al., that talks about doing this.

**EDIT**: the view (`Create.cshtml`). The original has more fields but I've omitted them like in the model:

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Order</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: How do you *display* the data? The `Display` attribute specifies the order. It's up to the controls or your custom code to respect that order. The built-in controls do so. All commercial controls do so as well.

Comment: BTW .NET 4.5 is out of support for several years now. The oldest supported version right now is 4.5.2 but even that goes out of support in a few months.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I'm only using this .NET because the book seems to. I do intend to switch to the latest after reading it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i've added the view